# What is the way to create socket on android platform from javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

I am making an application using phonejs. I want to create socket to get live data from server to display. I found HTML5 WebSocket working fine with web browser but not with mobile device. I used phonegap-build from http://build.phonegap.com to build application.

I tried to add 3rd party plugin(com.ququplay.websocket.websocket) of phonegap and run application with android mobile device but the application got crashed.

Here is how I work with WebSocket:

```
var initSocket = function(){
    try{
        var socket = new WebSocket(websocket.host);
        socket.onopen    = function(msg){ console.log("Welcome - Live Data"); };
        socket.onmessage = function(msg){
            console.log('-------- live data ------');
            // Here some work
        }
    }
    catch(ex){ console.log(ex); }   
};
```

Is there any other way to make socket run on android phone from javascript? Or any connector that can create socket on android phone from  javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I created cordova project with android platform and added WebSocket plugin from https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android.

I merged my application code in assets. This plugin handled socket related operations without need of changing my WebSocket related code.